# Avoiding copy when writing array to vector

Tags: c++

But if you want to prevent the 5000 copy (or more) of some potentially ugly heavy objects. Just for performance and ignore readable code you can do this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    int* a = (int*) malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    //int a[10];
    for( int i = 0; i<10;++i )
    {
        *(a + i) = i;
    }

    delete v._Myfirst; // ? not sure
    v._Myfirst = a;

    for( int i = 0; i<10;++i )
    {
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

simply replace the _Myfirst underlying "array". but be very careful, this will be deleted by the vector.

1. Does my delete/free of my first fail in some cases?
2. Does this depend on the allocator?
3. Is there a swap for that? There is the brand new swap for vectors, but how about from an array?

I had to interface with a code I cannot modify (political reasons), which provides me with arrays of objects and have to make them vector of objects.

The pointer seems the right solution, but it's a lot of memory jumps and I have to perform the loop anyway. I was just wondering if there was some way to avoid the copy and tell the vector, "now this is your underlying array".

I agree that the above is highly ugly and this is why I actually reserve and push in my real code. I just wanted to know if there was a way to avoid the loop.

Please don't answer with a loop and a push back, as obviously that's what my "real" code is already doing. If there is no function to perform this swap can we implement a safe one?

Comment: This code has undefined behavior

Comment: `delete v._Myfirst;` This code also appears to depend on the internal implementation details of your own standard library, which of course you should never do.

Comment: Why not simply do `v.push_back(i);` in the first loop, and forget about the array? What's the **real** point of the exercise? You seem to be busily jumping through hoops to solve a non-problem.

Comment: If you have some potentially ugly heavy objects, why not store pointers to them? You can copy them quickly enough.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik,@MaciejStachowski ==> question of speed. You misunderstood me, I know of to use a vector. I want to avoid the WHOLE loop, I have an array, I want to make it a vector. A vector is a wrapper of an "dynamic" array . Is it possible to avoid the whole loop and copy. ?

Comment: Why do you have an array? How did you populate it, and why couldn't you just populate the vector directly instead? Why this two-step dance?

Comment: superblib function( X* x ) // where x is not yet allocated

Comment: I'm provided with a lib which feeds me with arrays. But later I might add some objects in the "array" so a vector with extra reserved space would be perfect, but i'm provided an array, I have to live with it, right now, I just copy it. I was just wondering about performance. Pointer is not bad, but I still have the loop.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thanks, this is actually my question. Is there a way to perform this "swap" without relying on internal implementation ? If not why isn't Myfirst private ?

Comment: What is the exact signature of the function that "feeds you with arrays"? Does the function allocate the memory for the array, and you are responsible for freeing it eventually?

Comment: void foo( Object** objects ); yes it allocates and I must free it.

Comment: The way you show it, I don't see how that could possibly work. How does this function return the pointer to allocated memory, exactly? How do you call it?

Comment: sorry i was missing a star ( it's a typdef in fact ) I call it:

Object* object;
foo( &object );

Comment: I have no idea what this shit does. I do not have the source only a header.

Comment: Ok, so the function returns a pointer to a block of memory allocated with `malloc`, say. Suppose, for the sake of argument, that you managed to wrap this block in a vector, somehow. You say you want to add more elements to the vector - where exactly should the memory for these elements come from? It's not like vector has some magic pixie dust that can make allocated memory grow. The way vector does this is by allocating a larger block or memory, copying the contents over, then freeing the original block. So the contents are still copied, just in a different place.

Comment: Yes. I have an array with 5000 objects, I know Im gonna add more from 1000 to 2000. I reserve 7000 in my vector. copy the array, add my extra elements. Maybe some useless extra space ( but that's nearly always the case with a standard allocator )

Comment: For that, you don't need to muck in internal implementation details. `vector<int> v; v.reserve(7000); v.insert(v.begin(), arr, arr + 5000);` Et voila - a vector holding 5000 elements, with space for 2000 more. One copy was performed, inside the `insert` implementation.

Comment: Wait you are right i understood... what i say is fundamentally flown. If I swap the underlying array, the capacity() of the vector wont match the underlying array real allocated space!!! Ok I'm sorry for that guys i'm dum

Comment: v.insert(arr, arr + 5000); is a loop :) in its inside. But now i'm sure why I can't avoid it thanks to you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Question 1: does my delete/free of my first fail in some cases ?

Yes. You do not know how the memory for `_Myfirst` is allocated (apart from it uses the allocator). The standard does not specify that that the default allocator should use malloc to allocate the memory so you do not know if `delete` will work.

Also you are mixing allocation schemes.

You are allocating with `malloc()`. But expecting the `std::vector<>` to allocate with `new` (because you are calling delete).

Also even if the allocator did use new it would be uisng the array version of new and thus you would need to use the array version of delete to reclaim the memory.

> Question 2: does this depends on allocator ?

Yes.

> Question 3: is there a swap for that ? there is the brand new swap for vectors, but from an array ?

No.

To prevent expensive copies. Use `emplace_back()`.

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(10);            // reserve space for 10 objects (min).

for( int i = 0; i<10;++i )
{
    v.emplace_back(i);   // construct in place in the array (no copy).
}
```

Comment: Ok that was my point. There is no way to perform a "no loop swap" of the internal array without knowing the internal implementation of the allocator ?

Comment: @raphael: The `std::vector` and other `std` classes are closed for modification. You can use them via their public interface only. The creator of these objects can make internal assumptions to help in optimizations as long as those assumptions do not leak through the interface. If you reach past the interface and mangel the internals you may break some of those internal assumptions that were used in optimizations and thus break the code. Worse it could work in this release and then break mysteriously in the next release of the compiler.

Comment: thanks! I Never got downvoted that much about a purely "out of curiosity" technical question. I'm very surprised. But thanks to the few people who answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the way the vector behaves, don't use a vector.  Your code depends on implementation details that you MUST not rely upon.

Yes it's ugly as you said.   Make it pretty by using the correct container.

Which container you use depends on what operations you need on the container.  It may be something as simple as a C-style array will suit your needs.   It may be a vector of pointers, or shared pointers if you want the vector to manage the lifetime of the HeavyObjects.

---

In response to the need to increase the size of collection (see comments below):

std::vector guarantees that the underlying storage is contiguous, so if you increase the size, it will allocate a new larger buffer and copy the old one into the new (using the copy constructor for the objects if one exists.) Then swap the new buffer into place -- freeing the old one using its own allocator.

This will trash your memory unless the buffer you brute forced into the vector was allocated in a manner consistent with the vector's allocator.

So if your original array is big enough, all you need is a "maxUsed" size_t to tell you how big the collection is and where to put new entries.  If it's not big enough, then your technique will either fail horribly, or incur the copy costs you are trying to avoid.

Comment: politics matters... I'm provided an array. The vector is the right tool for my job after this "copy"

Comment: What operations do you need on the collection after the initial copy?

Comment: Increase the size of the array/vector

Comment: thaks that's what i just realized. so unless I can control the array allocation ( in which case the swap is not needed ) I will any way have my memory destroyed and a very undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<SomeUglyHeavyObject*> vect(5000, NULL);
for (int i=0; i<5000; i++)
{
    vect[i] = &arr[i];
}
```

There, avoids copying and doesn't muck with `std::vector` internals.

Comment: Yes but I still loop... what if I have 1 billion small ints ?